# Formatting a long filesystem path in Python

Tags: python, beginner

This is a follow up to [Log probe requests of WiFi devices](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83756/log-probe-requests-of-wifi-devices) focussing on a specific element of the code.

I have this line of code:

```
airport_path = "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport"
```

It seems to be too long for Python style standard. Can I shorten it or make it multiline?

Comment: What's there to review here? This is a single string assignment instruction. `[LEFT] [=] [RIGHT]` ...what do you want to shorten?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Constants should be named in `ALL_CAPS`, by convention.

You could [put multiple constants together](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation), such as

```
AIRPORT_PATH = "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/" \
    "Versions/Current/Resources/airport"
```

But PEP 8 also says that its own rules should not be applied dogmatically, and this is one place where I think a violation of the line-length limit is justified. It's not that much longer than 80 columns, and breaking up the string makes it less readable and searchable.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll leave it without splitting.