# Ensuring that external commands exist on the OS path

Tags: python, beginner

This is a follow-up to [Log probe requests of WiFi devices](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83756/log-probe-requests-of-wifi-devices), focusing on a specific element of the code.

Can I simplify this code and make it more readable?

```
if not os.path.isfile(args.tshark_path):
    print "tshark not found at path {0}".format(args.tshark_path)
    sys.exit(1)
if not os.path.isfile(args.ifconfig_path):
    print "ifconfig not found at path {0}".format(args.ifconfig_path)
    sys.exit(1)
if not osx:
    if not os.path.isfile(args.iwconfig_path):
        print "iwconfig not found at path {0}".format(args.iwconfig_path)
        sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just factor out the repetition:

```
for item, os_check in (('tshark', False), ('ifconfig', False), ('iwconfig', True)):
    if not os_check or osx:
        path = getattr(args, '{}_path'.format(item))
        if not os.path.isfile(path):
            print '{} not found at path {}'.format(item, path)
            sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Sorry, you don't understood the code. In the last condition the program only exits if the OS is not OSX.

Comment: @Helio updated, the principle is still the same.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I avoid surpassing the 79 characters on the line?

Comment: @Helio yes, you can add line breaks in the tuple of tuples just as you can in a function call.